# How to fix the header of gridview nested inside a gridview?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview with vertical and horizontal scrolling nested inside a main gridview.I have implemented horizontal and vertical scrolling for the nested gridview.I need to fix the header of this nested gridview during the horizontal and vertical scrolling. Please suggest me how can i do this?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridProjects" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="GridProjects_RowDataBound"  ShowFooter="true"   GridLines="None"  >                           
      <FooterStyle CssClass="grd_footer_bg grd_row_left" />
      <RowStyle CssClass=" grd_odd_row grd_row_left"  Wrap="false" />
      <HeaderStyle CssClass="grd_hdr_bg grd_row_left" Wrap="false"  Font-Bold="True"/>
      <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grd_evn_row grd_row_left" Wrap="false"/>  
      <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="padding" ItemStyle-Width="10px"        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Project Name">
            <ItemTemplate > 
              <table >
               <tr>
                <td>
                <a href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>',   'one','GridProjects_GridResources_3','400', '950' , '40' ,'true');"><img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Lesson Lists" border="0"
src="images/expand_button_white.jpg"  /></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
</td> 
<td>    <asp:Label ID="lblProjName" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                      </ItemTemplate>      
                </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="3">
                                                <div style="overflow: hidden;" id="DivHeaderRow">
                                                </div>

                                                   <div id="div<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>" onscroll="OnScrollDiv(this)" style="display: none; overflow:auto; position:relative; left: 25px;">                                               
                                                     <asp:Panel ID="pnlgrid" runat="server" Width="1309px" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
                                                        <asp:GridView ID="GridResources" runat="server" OnRowCreated="rowcreate" OnRowDataBound="GridResources_RowDataBound"   CssClass="grid" Width="900px" GridLines="Vertical"  
                                                  ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                                                             <FooterStyle CssClass="grd_footer_bg grd_row_left" />
                                    <RowStyle CssClass="grd_odd_row grd_row_left" Wrap="False" />
                                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="grd_higlight_row grd_row_left" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="grd_hdr_bg grd_row_left fixedHeader"  Font-Bold="True"  HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        Wrap="False" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grd_evn_row grd_row_left" Wrap="False" />
                                                            <Columns>
                                                            <%-- <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <a href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("ResourceID") %>', 'one');">
                                                <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("ResourceID") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Lesson Lists" border="0"
                                                    src="images/expand_button_white.jpg" /></a>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vacation/Comp Off">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvacatcoff"  MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Eval("ReasonVaction") %>' onkeypress="return AllowNumericOnly(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In Between Assignment">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtinbassign" MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Eval("ReasonInBtnAssignments") %>' onkeypress="return AllowNumericOnly(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Internal Project">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtintproj" MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Eval("ReasonInternalProjects") %>' onkeypress="return AllowNumericOnly(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Training">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txttraining" MaxLength="10" Width="80px" Text='<%# Eval("ReasonTraining") %>' onkeypress="return AllowNumericOnly(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="RevenueForecast" HeaderText="Revenue Forecast" />--%>
                                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Revenue Forecast">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRevenueForecast" Width="80px" Text='<%# Eval("RevenueForecast") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                              <FooterTemplate>
                                                              <asp:Label ID="lblRevenueTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                             </FooterTemplate>
                                             </asp:TemplateField>
                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" MaxLength="300" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                       </asp:GridView>
                                       </asp:Panel>
                                         </div>
                                         <div id="DivFooterRow" style="overflow:hidden">
                                         </div>
                                        </td>
                                       </tr>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'fix' the Header ?? With code, VisualTreeHelper can give you the parent / the child or children of any control so you can seek the Header using this.

Comment: Fixing the header means when we scroll the nested gridview vertically, The nested gridview header should be static during scrolling,only the nested gridview rows should be scrolled

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to set a fixed header on an html table (rendered by a GridView server control) using the jQuery plugin [tableScroll](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/).

To try it, look at the demo, find your client-side ID of the table rendered by your GridView (you might want to set `ClientIdMode="static"` on the GridView so that your client-side ID is the same as it is server-side).  Then you can call something like:

```
$('#GridProjects').tableScroll({height:400});
```

Assuming you have script references to js files jQuery and tableScroll, and a link to the tableScroll CSS file.

If you don't want to set your `ClientIDMode="static"`, you could set the tableScroll like this:

```
$('#<%= GridProjects.ClientID %>').tableScroll({height:400});
```